# WARNING: Waiting for service sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.1.0 rev. 001564 (WDP Package XP0) and I get this error:

```
WARNING: (sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine - sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService
WARNING: (sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine - sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService
WARNING: (sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine - sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService
WARNING: (sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService)' to start...
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Failed to start service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine -
sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService (sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService)'.
At C:\ResourceFiles\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:80 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
```

Any idea? Thank you.

**Possible Cause:**

The untrusted certificates installed under the Trusted folder.

**Solution:**

Execute this command as Administrator, delete the database and run the script of installation again:

```
Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
```

[image]

***Please add a comment if this solution works for you.***

Comment: This solution of moving certs with issuer & subject is not equal in Local/Root moved to different location worked for me. Thanks to @sitecorey for pointing me to the solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is telling you that the service that xConnect is trying to install for the Marketing Automation Engine is not starting. This could stem from a number of different causes. However, generally, it could be a result of either permission issues with the service and or folder. The image below shows the services in Windows.

[image]

### Troubleshooting Steps

1. Try to start the service manually from the Windows Services window.
2. Check the Windows Event Log. When services fail, it logs a message in the **Application** Log which is usually helpful enough to understand what's going.
3. Ensure that you are using a PowerShell window as ***An Administrator***. The SIF process installs Windows Services, which needs administrator access to the machine.
4. Look at the xConnect Marketing Automation Engine logs. See below.
5. Enure that **Local Service** account has full control over the `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\*.xconnect` folder and it's subfolders and files.

### Looking at MA Engine Logs

Another step of troubleshooting is to look at the MA Engine logs. It could be the service is throwing an error.  Look in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\*.xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\logs`

[image]

Check errors in this log. A properly working engine will have the following log:

```
2018-12-02 14:10:47.423 -05:00 [Information] SystemPerformanceCounters Constructor, Instance:MarketingAutomation, Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sxp910.xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Diagnostics, CounterFilePattern: *.json
2018-12-02 14:10:49.952 -05:00 [Information] Engine configurator "PoolWorkerRatioEngineConfigurator" will create 8 pool workers
2018-12-02 14:10:49.962 -05:00 [Information] Adding pool worker with ID 'c21836e0-97f7-4d1e-b881-265fcd9d9508'
2018-12-02 14:10:49.962 -05:00 [Information] Adding pool worker with ID '8ec6d988-cf33-4e45-bfb5-0e5f693d8ac4'
2018-12-02 14:10:49.963 -05:00 [Information] Adding pool worker with ID '1e69254a-79c2-4c3a-b665-d130c9c06a78'
2018-12-02 14:10:49.963 -05:00 [Information] Adding pool worker with ID 'a55ae68e-a3b0-4b80-9978-7f7f939c154c'
2018-12-02 14:10:49.963 -05:00 [Information] Adding pool worker with ID 'c5b5be38-107d-45aa-ab24-5211638a1123'
2018-12-02 14:10:49.963 -05:00 [Information] Adding pool worker with ID '827b6de6-6e5f-42ab-9862-4c805bfd26cb'
2018-12-02 14:10:49.963 -05:00 [Information] Adding pool worker with ID '36fd10a3-165d-4a10-9be4-195ff964a3c6'
2018-12-02 14:10:49.963 -05:00 [Information] Adding pool worker with ID '4132a778-c5d5-4532-9ca8-fb202d73c32c'
2018-12-02 14:10:49.965 -05:00 [Information] Starting workers
2018-12-02 14:10:49.968 -05:00 [Information] Starting worker with ID 'c21836e0-97f7-4d1e-b881-265fcd9d9508'
```

### Resolving

Once you have identified what the issue is and have resolved it (meaning that you can manually start the windows service without error), try to rerun the Sitecore 9.1 SIF installation script. You may need to uninstall the services that were set up by the previous installation of SIF.

### Last Resort

Delete everything and try again. Making sure that you have an Administator Powershell command prompt and that you have the correct version of Sitecore Install Framework installed.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried to start the three services, two started and "sc910.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService" not, I check the Event Viewer and I get this messages: (System: An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request.) (Application: Faulting application name: maengine.exe, version: 3.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xc338dcf1
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.17134.407, time stamp: 0x99042cc0
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll)

Comment: I've edited my answer to add checking the MA Engine log. See above.

Comment: I check the log and if found this: 2018-12-02 21:26:57.724 +00:00 [Error] Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service.
System.InvalidOperationException: This configuration has not been initialized. Please call the initialize method before using it.
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.CheckInitialized()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.get_CurrentModel()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)

Comment: I would add that to your question.  This just seems like a completely failed installation.  I would delete everything and try again.  Make sure that you are using a PowerShell Window in Administrator mode when running SIF and that you have updated SIF correctly.

Comment: I will do it now, and I let you know, thank you for your help you are the best.

Comment: Your welcome, and Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange. If you find this answer helpful, feel free to upvote. Don't forget that part of your responsibility for asking a question is to select an answer. If you feel that no answer is the correct one, then you can wait. But upvote answers that are helpful, and downvote answers that are not.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue, with the same error in the automation app logs. Already retried from scratch 6 times. Ended up creating a ticket with support.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same issue and looking into the Automation Engine logs I could see that before the failed initialisation, it was throwing an xConnect connection error:

*Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden*

Looking at the IIS logs, it was throwing a 403.16 and some googling led me to this post:
https://sitecorecorner.com/tag/ssl/

which in turn took me to the solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247462/http-error-403-16-client-certificate-trust-issue

The issue was that there were some non-self-signed certificates in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities (i.e. Root) store. The second post listed above provides some handy Powershell that fixed the problem by removing the offending certificates. The certificates in my case were installed as part of my company's standard Windows 10 image.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. My solution was to enable Windows ASP.NET 4.7 Application Development Features. These settings are found in Windows Features -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> ASP.NET 4.7

The Marketing Automation service would not start because xConnect was not working correctly. Enabling the appropriate Windows Features fixed xConnect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. What happens is that during startup, the marketing service tries to connect to xConnect. But xConnect could not startup. Hence the marketing service failed, and thus the installation.

The reason xConnect could not startup was due to this error in the event logs:

```
Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile.
Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.
```

This has to do with the custom user that is created in the script and the identityType set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity" on the application pool of xConnect.

This issue can be resolved by setting "Load User Profile" to false in the advanced settings of the application pool.

**Solution**

To fix the install script so that no manual interventions are required edit these files:

- xconnect-xp0.json
- sitecore-xp0.json
- identityserver.json

In each file search for

```
"identityType": "ApplicationPoolIdentity"
```

and change this to

```
"identityType": "ApplicationPoolIdentity",
"loadUserProfile": "False"
```

Comment: Thank you @Bart Verdonck, Setting Load User Profile resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me I discovered that I had the wrong XConnectCollectionService and XConnectReferenceDataService URLs in the PS script.

Answer (score 0):

I found another issue which may aid in solving the issue...  In examining the XCONNECT_CLIENT certificate stored under Personal certificates (created during the installation process using SIF), I updated the access level on the xconnect user to full control.  After I did that, I was able to start the Marketing Automation Service manually and complete installation of Sitecore 9.3 using SIF, making sure to perform this step before it reached starting the service step so I can complete the installation.

[image: Using MMC to examine XCONNECT_CLIENT Certificate]

I hope this helps...