# Certificate Error starting the Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine service

Tags: xconnect, upgrade, marketing-automation

I am upgrading Sitecore xConnect from version 9.0.1 to 9.1.1 and after following steps from the `Sitecore-911-Upgrade-Guide`, I copy & pasted the provided files and folders to the `xConnect` folder. But now I cannot start `Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine` service anymore.

I am getting this error in the logs:

```
"The certificate was not found. Store: My, Location: LocalMachine, FindType: FindByThumbprint, FindValue..."
```

I checked all connection strings to check thumbprint and they look fine. Any suggestion? It is weird that it doesn't work after copying files, especially since I didn't change any `App_Config` folders.

Comment: Make sure the certificate permissions allows the service to access it.

Comment: I use the same App_Config folder as for version before copy & pasting files and it worked then.

Comment: Check the certificate with the thumbprint exists.  If it does check that the issuer cert is in the root store and all are certs have not expired.  Expiration date is based on license file.  Have a look at my answer on this ticket https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/20155/2402